# Office 365 email attachments to S3 Bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I want a python script to get email attachments from a specific User and store it in my s3 bucket. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the code I'm using and it throws the error "login failed".

```
import imaplib

username = '******'
password = '******'

try:
    with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com') as imap4:
        imap4.login(username, password)

        # retrieve a list of the mailboxes and select one
        result, mailboxes = imap4.list()
        imap4.select("inbox")

except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Error without try/except:

```
imap4.login(username, password)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 603, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.error: b'LOGIN failed.'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code, and all error messages, should be posted as plain text.

Comment: That try/except block is hiding most of the error traceback.  Take out the try/except and post the full error.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have added the error without try/except in my post.

Comment: are you sure the username and password is correct? and are you using the correct domain name ('outlook.office365.com')? Is this for a personal or a business account?

Comment: @DWKOT Yes, the username and password I am using are correct, I am not sure about 'outlook.office365.com'. This is the company account that I am using.

Comment: Gotcha. I'd look into the domain name you might be using, and whether it needs to be something like '<your company>.outlook.office365.com' (this isn't from documentation or something, just a gut feeling on my part). I've also run into problems before in my own personal adventures where company security policy prevented mass download of email items like this. I got around it using a .NET script in Outlook, but again, depends on company permissions

Comment: @DWKOT There is no such company security policy.

Comment: so just to double check - the email address of the inbox receiving the attachments you're trying to use is '<username>@<company>.com'?

Comment: @DWKOT yes this is correct.

Comment: did you try swapping out 'outlook.office365.com' with 'company.com'?

Comment: @DWKOT yes, it is not working

Comment: Does the password have any "special" characters such as quote marks, backslash, ampersand, question mark, angle brackets, etc?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, $ sign.

Comment: I'm just guessing, and it seems like a long shot, but the dollar sign might be an issue.  Do you have the ability to change the password?